# How to replace a value in line of text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a stock file like below.

> Mo, M, 15,
>
> Jen, F, 14

I need to replace a variable in this text file so my code, as below, finds the line that I need to change, then puts these line values into a list. I try to use replace but it doesn't work and for some reason my whole file deletes.

How do I place the value for example change Mo's age to 20?

My code is something like below:

```
newAge = "20"

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       if "Mo" in line:
           list = line.split()
           replace = list.replace(list[2]""this is value of age 15"", newAge)
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: It is possible to replace a word in a text file with another word *of the same size* (of stored text). If we can assume that all ages are shown in two consecutive decimal digits, changing the age is possible. This means no centenarians and children will need ages like `09`, but it is possible. That requires more sophistication than the OP has shown.

Comment: Saying you "don't have the actual code on you" suggests that you need to wait until your code is in front of you before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it should do the job:

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.lower().startswith( "mo," ):
           list = line.split(', ') 
           list[2] = str( newAge )
           line = ", ".join( list )
       result += line + '\n'
f = open("file.txt", 'w') # should be in 'wt or 'w' mode
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Comment: This makes my file look like ['M,o,,,,M,,,,1,5,,'] Why is that and how do i fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, You must split your line with the separating value which is ', '

Answer (score 1):

You can store your result in a new file as follows:

```
new_age = '20'

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if 'Mo' in line:
                new_file.write(line.replace(line.split(',')[2], ' ' + new_age))
            else:
                new_file.write(line)
```

**Explanation:**

For each line in the old file, if `Mo` exists then, we split the line and replace the 3rd item with `new_age` in the new file, else, we just write the line without change.